# C line with '?' and ':'

Tags: c

Can someone help me to understand how this line work ? I know what it do but the '?' and ':' are not clear for me..

```
C code:

(buff[i - 1] == '\n') ? my_printf("%s", buff) : my_printf("%s\n", buff);
```

Thanks

Pivot

Comment: That is the ternary conditional operator. It should be explained in your text.

Comment: It is the ternary operator.

Comment: So .. many .. duplicates .. I can't pick one.

Comment: It's also a *bad* example of using the ternary conditional operator; it should not be used as a control structure like this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That statement equals

```
if (buff[i - 1] == '\n')
    my_printf("%s", buff);
else
    my_printf("%s\n", buff);
```

Comment: This misses the important point that `a ? b : c` is an *expression*, not a statement.

Comment: @chepner `a ? b : c` is an expression, but `a ? b : c;` is a statement.

Answer (score 0):

It means: If first part is true, do the second part or else do the third part.

In your case, if last character of buff (buff[i-1]) is equal with end line ('\n'), print the buff. But if buff doesn't end with end line ('\n'), you print buff and then end line ("%s\n")